# VBA, Returning a String in a Function, Beyond Insane

Tags: vba, function, return

```
Function GetPath() As String

Dim sFilepath As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

sFilepath = GetFolder()

If sFilepath = "" Then
  MsgBox ("Invalid File Path! Select a File Path for the Folders.")
End If

End Function
```

This is beyond insane. All I want to do is return a value, a String, but when I type

```
Return sFilepath
```

At the end of the function I get a compiler error. I'm transitioning from Java to VBA and this is frustrating and embarrassing me. Gurus of the Internet, why can't I insert that Return statement and how do I do it correctly?

Comment: Return is not keyword in VBA.  Use [FunctionName] = xxx.  See Brian's answer.  It's a headache you'll have to live with if you moving between VBA and .NET (one of many).

Comment: @GordonBell well technically it *is* a keyword. It's meant to work hand in hand with the anticated `GoSub` keyword though, to goto-jump to a sub-routine and then jump back to the instruction that follows. i.e. `Return` exists as part of VBA's secret spaghetti sauce recipe.

Comment: Yes, I should have added "for returning Function values".

Comment: @Mat'sMug "VBA's secret spaghetti sauce recipe" LOL

Answer (score 4):

In VBA, Return is used for a different purpose.  So instead of:

```
Return sFilePath
```

You need to write:

```
GetPath = sFilePath
```

Comment: "**This is beyond insane**" still applies.  I just discovered this today also because I needed to have a small custom Excel function.  I thought I'd seen as crazy Microsoft could get with BATCH script insanity.